# Invoking jMeter from the command line with 64-bit directive loses the class

Tags: java, jmeter, jdk1.7

We were running 32-bit JDK and jMeter 2.6, and were running into heap memory issues when simulating 8000 users spread out over the course of an hour.

We upgraded to 64-bit Java, and jMeter 2.12.

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

When we run from the command line requesting a 4Gb heap (the server has 32Gb), we receive the message that the initial heap size is too large.

```
set JVM_ARGS="-Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1G" jmeter.sh
```

When we add the option -d64 to JVM_ARGS, we no longer receive the error about the heap size, but it no longer finds the class

```
set JVM_ARGS="-d64 -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1G" jmeter.sh
```

Pointing it to the directory seems to have no effect

```
set JVM_ARGS="-d64 -Xms4G -Xmx4G -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=1G -cp mypath" jmeter.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Looking into `jmeter.sh` it seems you're trying to run JMeter on Linux or MacOSX. I believe you need to remove `set` word (or replace it with `export`)
2. Given you have correct `java` executable in PATH providing `-d64` option shouldn't be required. Something like:

   ```
    JAVA_HOME=/path/to/64-bit/jdk && export JAVA_HOME
    PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH && export PATH
   ```
3. You can edit `jmeter` script and amend the following lines:

   ```
   HEAP="-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
   NEW="-XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m"
   ```

   "Telling" Jmeter to use [Concurrent Mark Sweep (CMS) Garbage Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/cms.html) can also improve JMeter-side performance greatly. The relevant line is:

   ```
   -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
   ```

See  [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article for more information on getting the most from your JMeter installation.

Comment: Actually it's running on Windows Server 8.1.